# Expect an instance of a specific class as a keyword argument

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to allow a class to receive an instance of another class as an argument in Rspec/Rspec-mocks.

The context is I am trying to create Rspec tests for Puppet (i.e. a Ruby app).

I want to say in Rspec "something like" -

```
allow(Puppet::FileServing::Content.indirection).
  to receive(:find).with(
    "puppet:///modules/profile/logstash/logstash.json",
    an_instance # an instance of Puppet::Node::Environment would go  here
).and_return('bar')
```

Creating a fake instance of a class doesn't seem to be an option, because the instance that is received depends on values computed during the run.

Thus, in my Pry debugger I see this:

```
 =>  99:               Puppet::FileServing::Content.indirection.find(
    100:                 self[:source],
    101:                 :environment => catalog.environment_instance
    102:               )
```

and

```
[1] pry(#<Puppet::Type::Elasticsearch_template>)> catalog.environment_instance
=> <Puppet::Node::Environment:70286646297160 @name="rp_env" @manifest="/Users/alexharvey/git/elk/spec/fixtures/manifests" @modulepath="/Users/alexharvey/git/elk/spec/fixtures/modules" >
```

Where I'm stuck is I don't know how to tell the test to "allow" an instance of the Puppet::Node::Environment to receive what I see above in the debugger.

For instance, I don't know what the string "70286646297160" is (I guess it identifies the instance of the class somehow?).

And I can't refer to those paths, as they are specific to my laptop and the tests I am writing would then only work on my laptop.

So, how can I "tell" Rspec to "allow" this class instance I see in my debugger to be received, assuming it is possible to do so.

(I hope this makes sense. Obviously, this is a bit beyond my Rspec/Ruby knowledge.)

Comment: `hash_including(environment: instance_of(Puppet::Node::Environment))` instead of `an_instance `?

Comment: Wow that's exactly right. Could you make that an answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hash_including` together with `instance_of` matchers (*instead of what is written as `an_instance` in your example*):

```
hash_including(environment: instance_of(Puppet::Node::Environment))
```

Comment: And for anyone reading in the archives, the working version of the code is here https://github.com/alexharv074/elk/commit/8975f6d22c848c4e8fc894b8a6cffcc8d0474e16